# ASP.NET Identity Entity Framework for multiple applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2

the new db schema does not contain a table for storing applications and associating claims along with it. so is the recommended practiced to have a claim type 'Application' where a user can have zero or more records? What about permissions? Implement the same way but there is no direct correlation between the app and its associated claims.

any help would be great!

Comment: You can use Roles.Each Role can have a property which defines which application this Role belongs too. Also Role will contain Permissions.

Comment: role table does not contain that property. sure i can add it and modify code but was this the intent?

Comment: Identity is just a tool to help make your development easier not to limit your options. You can customize it anyway you want to. Many developers are actually developing permission based authorization systems by adding new properties to Roles and User entities